# External Accessory Framework...EADemo issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, bluetooth, ios-simulator

Exploring External Accessory Framework to connect iOS device via bluetooth. I downloaded Apple's EADemo project here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/EADemo/Introduction/Intro.html

But how do I test it? I'm new to XCode and Objective-C, so assume nothing. I opened the project file. I have it set to iPhone 5.1 Simulator at the top left. I click on the 'Product' menu...then I click on 'Run'. That opens the iOS simulator and it says no accessories connected. How do I get it to detect other bluetooth devices? If I go to general settings in the iOS simulator, bluetooth is set to off. If I move the switch to 'On'...it just spins and spins and spins and does nothing.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using built-in bluetooth, or an external BT dongle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, you can't test EADemo with the simulator. Only works with actual devices.